# How to show calendar entries for next day on a list including recurring events?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How do I get "tomorrow's events on a list from a calendar"  Using Date offset in CAML query?

From my efforts I get all the recurring events only but I do not get the "next day's" events.

The goal is to show a table listing "tomorrow's events" from calendar including recurring events.

Thank you in advance.